# How do I create a table using JQuery and insert XML data into the Cells?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, xml, html-table

I'm attempting to create a table 4 Columns Wide and 16 Rows High (16x4) in JQuery. The table is for a "Meet the Staff" page with 16 employees on it. This page contains information like their name, a small picture, their position in the company, and a small blurb describing them. This is laid out in a fashion so that each piece of info (name, their pic, position, and blurb) is contained in their own separate rows like so:

```
Name       Name        Name      Name
Image      Image       Image     Image
Position   Position    Position  Position
Blurb      Blurb       Blurb     Blurb

NEW ROW

Name       Name        Name      Name
Image      Image       Image     Image
Position   Position    Position  Position
Blurb      Blurb       Blurb     Blurb

etc....
```

The information is read in from an XML file. Here's a small segment of the file containing the entire management team (4 employees):

```
  <!--Management-->
  <management>
    <name>Daniel Duffy</name>
    <position>Manager of Mechanical Services</position>
    <blurb>Over a decade of mechanical experience, nine of those years working souly on GM vehicles, Dan knows the ins and outs of almost all North American GM vehicles like the back of his hand.</blurb>
  </management>
  <management>
    <name>Kelly Assise</name>
    <position>Manager of Customer Service</position>
    <blurb>A degree in Communication Studies and an outgoing upbeat attitude makes Kelly the perfect candidate for our Customer Service Dept.</blurb>
  </management>
  <management>
    <name>Aly McAvoy</name>
    <position>Manager of Sales</position>
    <blurb>A well-rounded personality, with an aptitude for number crunching and excellent financial forsight, Aly McAvoy comes to us with over 6 years experience in the auto parts field.</blurb>
  </management>
  <management>
    <name>Rich Sarlous</name>
    <position>Manager of Marketing</position>
    <blurb>Business and Communication careers run in the family. Rich Sarlous is no exception. Fresh out of college, smart as a whip, graduating with a Masters in Business/Marketing.</blurb>
  </management>
```

This will be created 4 times over (for all 16 employees). Here's an example from my current code that I'm hoping to delete.

```
<div class="infoBlurb"><table id="employeeTable">
        <!--Directors-->
        <tr><td class="employeeName1"></td><td class="employeeName2"></td><td class="employeeName3"></td><td class="employeeName4"></td></tr>
        <tr><td class="employeePic1"></td><td class="employeePic2"></td><td class="employeePic3"></td><td class="employeePic4"></td></tr>
        <tr><td class="employeePos1"></td><td class="employeePos2"></td><td class="employeePos3"></td><td class="employeePos4"></td></tr>
        <tr><td class="employeeBlurb1"></td><td class="employeeBlurb2"></td><td class="employeeBlurb3"></td><td class="employeeBlurb4"></td></tr>
```

**Having 3 more blocks of those rows looks messy**, hence why I want to create the table using JQuery. There must be a way to do this without me having to create 16 different cell classes for each bit of data and 16 different CSS classes for each cell.

I have written the correct Jquery too loop through the XML file and display all of the data in the html i have written like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../stylesheets/employees.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            var x = 1;
            $(xml).find('directors').each(function () {
                var name = $(this).find('name').text()
                $(".employeeName" + x).text(name);
                var position = $(this).find('position').text()
                $(".employeePos" + x).html(position);
                var blurb = $(this).find('blurb').text()
                $(".employeeBlurb" + x).html(blurb);
                x++
            });
            $(xml).find('management').each(function () {
                var name = $(this).find('name').text()
                $(".employeeName" + x).text(name);
                var position = $(this).find('position').text()
                $(".employeePos" + x).html(position);
                var blurb = $(this).find('blurb').text()
                $(".employeeBlurb" + x).html(blurb);
                x++
            });
            $(xml).find('supervisor').each(function () {
                var name = $(this).find('name').text()
                $(".employeeName" + x).text(name);
                var position = $(this).find('position').text()
                $(".employeePos" + x).html(position);
                var blurb = $(this).find('blurb').text()
                $(".employeeBlurb" + x).html(blurb);
                x++
            });
            $(xml).find('juniorSupervisor').each(function () {
                var name = $(this).find('name').text()
                $(".employeeName" + x).text(name);
                var position = $(this).find('position').text()
                $(".employeePos" + x).html(position);
                var blurb = $(this).find('blurb').text()
                $(".employeeBlurb" + x).html(blurb);
                x++
            });
        }
    });
});
```

But I'm not sure how to incorporate HTML into that or if I'm even doing it right..

On top of all this, I want to be able to filter this table between displaying all 16 employees to displaying just one department using a drop down menu. I have the drop down menu ready to rock, but I figure I'd throw that bit of info in there in case that means that it'd have to be coded differently.

Any help is much appreciated,

Comment: did you try my suggestion below? Did it help you?

Answer (score 0):

**1. use client side templating**

To make your life easier I would recommend that you use client side templating.
Then it is way easier to change the layout afterwards and you do not have to dig through your jQuery code. Handlebars is a good solution for that:

http://handlebarsjs.com/

**2. transform xml to json**

the only thing is that Handlebars expects JSON data and not XML. You may try to convert the XML to JSON as well with this:

http://goessner.net/download/prj/jsonxml/

There is also a link to a good article about XML-JSON conversion at the bottom